# Delete statement not working on query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table  `BK_178_ABC`. I want to perform delete statement on this table only when some condition is satisfied:

My total count on this table is:

```
select count(*) from BK_178_ABC; ==>22024727
```

I have this condition below,if it satisfies then I need to delete from this BK_178_ABC table.So,I first calculated what is the total no of rows going to be deleted.So,I tried the statement below.

```
SELECT Count(*)                                    
FROM
BK_178_ABC  a
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE UPPER(type) = 'MOOV' AND UPPER(buyer) = 'KERA') gr
    ON
        SubStr (a.PS_UNIQUE_ID,-8)  = gr.SOURCEID
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE UPPER(type) = 'MOOV' AND UPPER(buyer) = 'KERA') gr2
    ON
        a.GROUP_NBR   = gr2.SOURCEID
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM droptable drp
  WHERE
    COALESCE(gr.ROLLUPGROUPID, gr2.ROLLUPGROUPID, SubStr(a.ps_unique_id,-8))=drp.groupid
);
```

So,the count to be deleted is :  **2902563**.

I tried two delete statement but,both of them gave me wrong count.Since,my expected count is **2902563**,but I am not getting the correct result.

```
DELETE FROM bk_178_abc     WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   bk_178_abc a 
                      LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                                 FROM   xyz 
                                 WHERE  Upper(type) = 'MOOV' 
                                        AND Upper(buyer) = 'KERA') gr 
                             ON Substr (a.ps_unique_id, -8) = gr.sourceid 
                      LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                                 FROM   xyz 
                                 WHERE  Upper(type) = 'MOOV' 
                                        AND Upper(buyer) = 'KERA') gr2 
                             ON a.group_nbr = gr2.sourceid 
               WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                              FROM   droptable drp 
                              WHERE  COALESCE(gr.rollupgroupid, 
                                     gr2.rollupgroupid, 
                                     Substr(a.ps_unique_id, -8)) = drp.groupid)) 
;
```

It,emptied the whole table, as total count deleted I see is : **22024727**

So,I refactored this above code again,tried another delete statment:

```
 DECLARE
    
          begin
            DELETE FROM BK_178_ABC  a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE UPPER(type) = 'MOOV' AND UPPER(buyer) = 'KERA') gr,
             xyz gr2,
            droptable  drp  WHERE   SubStr (a.PS_UNIQUE_ID,-8)  = gr.SOURCEID AND a.GROUP_NBR   = gr.SOURCEID
              AND   COALESCE(gr.ROLLUPGROUPID, gr2.ROLLUPGROUPID, SubStr(a.ps_unique_id,-8))=drp.groupid );  
            Dbms_Output.put_line(SQL%ROWCOUNT);
            END;
```

I see that rowcount is **zero**. What is the problem in my sql statment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IN as follows:

```
DELETE FROM bk_178_abc     WHERE  rowid in (SELECT a.rowid
               FROM   bk_178_abc a 
                      LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                                 FROM   xyz 
                                 WHERE  Upper(type) = 'MOOV' 
                                        AND Upper(buyer) = 'KERA') gr 
                             ON Substr (a.ps_unique_id, -8) = gr.sourceid 
                      LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                                 FROM   xyz 
                                 WHERE  Upper(type) = 'MOOV' 
                                        AND Upper(buyer) = 'KERA') gr2 
                             ON a.group_nbr = gr2.sourceid 
               WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                              FROM   droptable drp 
                              WHERE  COALESCE(gr.rollupgroupid, 
                                     gr2.rollupgroupid, 
                                     Substr(a.ps_unique_id, -8)) = drp.groupid)) 
;
```

Comment: can you tell me if i dont write this rowid in then whole my table gets deleted. Why it is happening so?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a different technique with rather better performance. In your case you could use CTAS/TRUNCATE/BULK COLLECT, as you want to delete more than 10% of the rows in the table ( 2902563 of 22024727 ). In my experience, when you want to eliminate more than 10% of the rows or your table, and the number exceeds a million, this technique is faster. However, keep in consideration that INSERT APPEND will lock the table, as it is a direct path operation.

An approximation with this technique would be

```
alter session enable parallel dml ;

alter session enable parallel ddl ;

alter session force parallel query ;

create table res_bk_178_abc parallel compress  
for 
select * FROM bk_178_abc   WHERE  rowid in (SELECT a.rowid
               FROM   bk_178_abc a 
                      LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                                 FROM   xyz 
                                 WHERE  Upper(type) = 'MOOV' 
                                        AND Upper(buyer) = 'KERA') gr 
                             ON Substr (a.ps_unique_id, -8) = gr.sourceid 
                      LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                                 FROM   xyz 
                                 WHERE  Upper(type) = 'MOOV' 
                                        AND Upper(buyer) = 'KERA') gr2 
                             ON a.group_nbr = gr2.sourceid 
               WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                              FROM   droptable drp 
                              WHERE  COALESCE(gr.rollupgroupid, 
                                     gr2.rollupgroupid, 
                                     Substr(a.ps_unique_id, -8)) = drp.groupid)) ;
                                     
truncate table bk_178_abc reuse storage;

insert /*+append parallel(a) */ into bk_178_abc a select /*+parallel(b) */ * from res_bk_178_abc b; 

commit;

drop table res_bk_178_abc purge;
```

Basically, in this scenario, instead of deleting almost 3 million rows or 22 , which is expensive, I create a table with the rows I want to keep, truncate the original one, and insert back the data using a direct path operation with parallel enable.

In the create table as select (CTAS) you could use hints to force parallel query, but as I have no idea of your data model and how many indexes you have on those tables, I did not touch that part. @Tajesh was right in include the rowid reference to get only the number of rows that have to be deleted.

Regards